# Random privileges and badges popping up

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges

I logged in this morning to find that I'd received the privilege of protecting questions, which requires about half the reputation that I currently have, and, upon logging into Meta, that I'd earned the "Citizen Patrol" badge for my first flagged post: an operation which I'd done some time ago, and haven't done recently.

[image: Protect questions screenshot]

[image: Citizen Patrol badge]

Are these new?  Did something get reset? Is it a bug?

Comment: I think that these are new priveledges and badges that have been added. I had the same thing happen.

Comment: I had the citizen patrol badge as well today randomly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are new privileged and changed badges, so this is by design.